# Testing a web app for macs - is IPad ok?

Tags: macos, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Many of my clients use Macs and I'm getting weekly emails about bugs in my web-app software that are Mac only issues.
I have a limited budget so I'm hesitating going out any buying a $1,200 Mac for testing.

Would an iPad work?

Or would that **not be the same kind of browser rendering** as a Mac Book?

Comment: I mean, the iPad can't display any Flash. That might be an issue to you... (I'm assuming there might be something that exists if you jailbreak the iPad...)

Comment: In what way is it a Mac only issue? Safari? Does it do it on Safari for Windows? Or does it do it in Firefox/Chromium/etc. too?

Answer (score 2):

can I recommend a [$700](http://www.apple.com/macmini/) mac then?

The biggest benefit is, that with virtual machines, you can now create a testing environment for nearly every system you wish to be a client on

Answer (score 2):

The iPad Safari is more based on the iPhone mobile safari rather than the desktop Safari. You may have better luck getting a Mac Mini, or searching eBay for a used Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm… why has nobody mentioned yet, that Apple distributes Safari [for Windows](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/)? For free.

You are not very specific about the kinds of problems your uses report. I would be very interested in which of those are not testable with Safari on Windows!

Comment: Agreed. There is no difference in how OSX renders content, since it's the browser doing the work.

Comment: @jeek: not so fast! there are differences. font rendering comes to mind.

Comment: @jeek: Also, there's Chrome/Firefox/Opera for Mac. Some browsers are updated on the Windows side that aren't updated yet on the Mac, Chrome for example.

Comment: @hop/@robert - This I do agree with. These are very minute differences though, and not _too much_ you can do about them. If it's CSS3 and bleeding-edge features, then you shouldn't really be using those to begin with on a live environment if it's crippling the UX on browsers who don't support it. Take -webkit properties for example. Awesome features, but not very practical in a live environment.

Comment: ok, so I load this page on win XP with Safari,
http://billetagent.eweb703.discountasp.net/vejledning.aspx the "offline image" is not a link. Client has a fancy super mac and is running firefox. He says it's a link.

Comment: @aron: why do you test it in safari when your client (the one with the problem, i assume) uses firefox? also: should there be a link or shouldn't there?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to mimic common mac browsers than buying common mac hardware. Look into browser emulation products like browsercam.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one said it directly yet, iPad does not render exactly the same as Safari on 10.6, nor can interactions be tested because one is gesture and touch based and the other is keyboard and mouse.  You're cheapest option is the [$700 Mac Mini](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_mini) plugged in to your existing input devices.

Unfortunately, because apple forbids the virtualization of it's OS ([PDF:Section 2.A](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx106.pdf)), you can't find [anyone](http://litmusapp.com/) who will take browser shots in any [reasonable amount of time](http://browsershots.org/).  Of course, screen shots will only really help you if it's a rendering bug.  If it's interaction, $700 isn't all that much more than $500, plus, you get a Mac! ;)